# JavaScript returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this running

```
$('#info').replaceWith('<div id="infobox" class="reveal-modal">'+$('#info').contents()+'<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>');
```

but It just gives me [object Object]. As I only replace it with $('#info').contents() things work fine.

Comment: Well, `$('#info').contents()` is an object and the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`. You cannot just concatenate strings with arbitrary objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    var content = $('#info').get(0).outerHTML;
    $('#info').replaceWith('<div id="infobox" class="reveal-modal">'+content+'<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>');
})
```

The `$('#info').get(0).outerHTML` returns `<div id="info">anything</div>`. But if just want the content, use `$('#info').html()`, that returns `anything`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to maintain the existing content and place it inside an outer div try using `wrap()` and you can call `after()` to adding the closing anchor.

```
$('#info').wrap('<div id="infobox" class="reveal-modal">')
    .after('<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>')
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/qU4s3/**

---

Could also be written like this:

```
$('#info')
    .wrap($('<div>', { id: "infobox", "class": "reveal-modal"}))
    .after($('<a>', { "class": "close-reveal-modal", html: "&#215;" }));
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/qU4s3/2/**

Comment: One thing though, `.append` should be `.after`, and `wrap` should include it.

Comment: Your updated version looks even better and makes sense to me, testing.

Comment: +1 Best answer so far as it doesn't have to parse HTML unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

`.contents()` returns a jQuery object, what you want is `.text()` or `.html()` depending on if `#info` contains other elements.

```
$('#info').replaceWith('<div id="infobox" class="reveal-modal">'+$('#info').text()+'<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

starts with `$('#info').contents().`   <-- like this

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem? What is the trailing dot for? If you'd just insert it into the OP's code, you'd get a syntax error.